# How can I increase integer value by click on like button in firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here I have used m Like.set Text but don't know what will be next step.

```
{  public void setLikeBtn(final String post_key){

            mDatabaseLike.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


                    if (mAuth.getCurrentUser()==null){

                    }

                   else if (dataSnapshot.child(post_key).hasChild(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid())){


                       mLike.setText("Likes"+"");
                        mLikeButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.red_thumb);

                    }else {

                        mLikeButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_thumb_up_black_24dp);



                    }
                }

}

Database references
{
 mDatabaseLike = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Likes");

            mDatabaseLikesCount = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Likes");
}
```

Comment: could you place your db structure?

Comment: Please look at the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45276327/how-to-increase-a-value-in-firebase-realtime-database
i hope that helps..

Comment: it's like  Likes:  Photo id number:  UID

Comment: just like yogesh url referred structure